# Waterpay calculator else if statements

Tags: javascript

I've been going over this question now for a couple of days and I'm still no closer to getting it right or understanding as to how to get it to run properly.

This is the current code I have:

```
let waterPay = prompt("Please enter the amount of water you use to get a price you need to pay, thank you!");

if  (waterPay < 6000) {
    console.log("The number is below 6000");
    console.log (waterPay / 1000); //The outcome of this must be saved as a different let 
    console.log (waterPay * 15.73);// outcome of the above times by this amount
    }
    else if (waterPay > 6000  && waterPay <= 10500) {
    console.log("The number is between 6000 and 10500");
    }
    else if (waterPay > 10500  && waterPay <= 35000) {
    console.log("The number is between 10500 and 35000");
    }
     else if (waterPay > 35000) {
    console.log("The number is above 35000");
    }
```

What my code needs to do is take an input from the user stating how many litres of water they use, you can see in the code that depending on the amount of litres they use it should print out how much they owe.

The table above states that the first 6 000 litres will cost R15.73 per kilolitre.
Next, water consumption above 6 000 litres but below 10 500 litres will be
charged at R22.38 per kilolitre. Therefore, a household that has used 8000
litres will pay R139.14 (15.73 x 6 + 22.38 x 2). The table carries on in this
manner.

Im battling to figure out how I should go about working this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between what you want to do and what this code actually does?  And what "table" are you talking about?

Comment: So at the moment the code is simply printing out where the number the user falls ( in which category) .

Comment: So you haven't even tried to compute "how much they owe".

Comment: Howdy scott, That's literally what my question is referring to and what I need help with. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have the formulae you need; what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure needed is something that pairs rates with usage thresholds. The last threshold is effectively infinite, to catch any usage above the highest.  The logic is to `find()` the right rate object and multiply that rate tier's rate by the usage.

```js
let rateData = [{
    upTo: 6000,
    rate: 15.73
  },
  {
    upTo: 10500,
    rate: 22.38
  },
  {
    upTo: 35000,
    rate: 34.0. // made this one up, not in the OP
  },
  {
    upTo: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    rate: 50.0. // made this one up, not in the OP
  }
];

function rateDatumForUsage(usage) {
  return rateData.find(r => usage <= r.upTo);
}

function costForUsage(usage) {
  const rateDatum = rateDatumForUsage(usage);
  return usage * rateDatum.rate;
}

console.log(`The cost of using 5000 units is (15.73*5000) ${costForUsage(5000)}`)
console.log(`The cost of using 10000 units is (22.38*10000) ${costForUsage(10000)}`)
console.log(`The cost of using 100000 units is (50*100000) ${costForUsage(100000)}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Total cost should be calculated by steps.

This means that, for example, if the first 10 liters cost USD 2, the following 10 liters (from 10 to 20) cost USD 1 and from 20 cost will be USD 0.5, then the total cost for 30 liters will be: `10*2 + 10*1 + 10*0.5 = 35`.

This can only be achieved generically by looping. Here is the code:

```js
const steps = [
    6000,
    10500,
    35000
];

const rates = [
    10,
    20,
    30
];

function calculate(used) {
    let output = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
        if (used >= steps[i]) {
            output += steps[i] * rates[i];
        } else {
            output += (used - (steps[i - 1] || 0)) * rates[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(calculate(3000));
console.log(calculate(6000));
console.log(calculate(9000));
console.log(calculate(50000));
```